# How to send emails using real gmail account in PHP ATK4?

Tags: php, email, atk4

I tested sending emails and it works great.I used this:

```
<?php

class page_tmail extends Page_Abc {
public $skip = true;
function init() {
    parent::init();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $tmail = $this->add('TMail_Compat');
    $tmail->loadTemplate('test-mail');
    $tmail->set('from', 'hello@lexample.com');
    $tmail->send('asdf@gmail.com');
```

However I would like to send emails using a real gmail account with authentication.

Is it possible to tweak the code in doing so ? Or should I use something else like PHPmailer ... any suggestions ?

Comment: I think PHPMailer can do your work efficiently.